# How to click CTRL+P using Java and selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to send keyboard entry as CTRL+P using selenium. Please help.

My code looks like below:
getWebElement("Registration").sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "p"));

I have tried CTRL+A with the same code and it works without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to print, this is working for me

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("print()");
```

Comment: It works, thank. "Driver.ExecuteScript ("print()")"

Answer (score 0):

Try with actions

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL, "p")).build().perform();
```

Comment: this works for me. Could we also click Print/Cancel button onprint preview window using Actions? If yes, please help

Comment: the print window can be handled with autoit.